# Checking if the entity is on the list

Tags: java, list

I'm programming a friend system for my "forcefield" in a game called Minecraft. My idea is that if the player is not on the friend list, the player will it attack. The follow is all the code for my friend system and forcefield.

```
public static boolean friends = true;
public static List friend = new ArrayList();

public static void friendsList(){
    if(friends){
        try{
            File file = new File("friends.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            for(int i = 0; i < friend.size(); i++){
                bufferedwriter.write((new StringBuilder()).append((String) friend.get(i)).append("\r\n").toString());
            }
            bufferedwriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            System.err.print(exception.toString());
        }
    }
```

Forcefield:

```
if(Camb.nocheat){
    if (Camb.killaura)
      {

    hitDelay++;
        for(Object o: mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList){
    Entity e = (Entity)o;
        if(e != this && *******CHECK IF PLAYER IS NOT ON LIST******* && e instanceof EntityPlayer &&getDistanceToEntity(e) < 3.95D){
        if(e.isEntityAlive()){
        if(hitDelay >= 4){
            if(Camb.criticals){
               if(mc.thePlayer.isSprinting()==false){
                   if(mc.thePlayer.isJumping==false){
                   if(mc.thePlayer.onGround){
                       mc.thePlayer.jump();
                   }
                   }
               }


           }
        swingItem();
        mc.playerController.attackEntity(this, e);
        hitDelay = 0;
    break;

        }
        }
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

Adding/removing/clearing the friend list:

```
if(par1Str.startsWith("&friendadd")){
        Camb.friends = true;
        String as0[] = par1Str.split("");
        Camb.friend.add(as0[1]);
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage((new StringBuilder()).append("\2479[CAMB]\247e Added Friend.").append("").toString());
        Camb.friendsList();
        Camb.friends = false;
        return;
    }
    if(par1Str.startsWith("&friendremove")){
        Camb.friends = true;
        String as0[] = par1Str.split("");
        Camb.friend.remove(as0[1]);
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage((new StringBuilder()).append("\2479[CAMB]\247e Removed Friend.").append("").toString());
        Camb.friendsList();
        Camb.friends = false;
        return;
    }
    if(par1Str.startsWith("&friendclear")){
        Camb.friends = true;
        Camb.friend.clear();
        Camb.friendsList();
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\2479[CAMB]\247e Friends list cleared.");
        return;
    }
```

par1Str is the string entered in chat. Basically commands. Additionally, the &friendremove system is broken as well. I'm unsure why.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: What is "`*******CHECK IF PLAYER IS NOT ON LIST*******`" ? Is this code you have not written?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, I need it to check if the player is not on my friend list. If it is, attack.

Comment: _If it is, attack_, I hope you mean _isn't_, otherwise... you're not so friendly :)

Comment: Brad: Please accept the answer that helped you the most when you can, for all of your answers that are satisfiably answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use `friend.contains(e)`. It checks for equality albeit by iteration.

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Comment: It's just important to remember that `contains` is O(n) and design the caller accordingly.

Comment: And that you have to override equals in order for it to work correctly

Comment: @Gamb Only if using custom classes. If using Strings (eg Player names), it should work out of the box.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Mentioned "albeit by iteration.".

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas He's checking e, and e seems to be an `EntityPlayer` instance.

Comment: @Gamb I don't have the source of `Entity`/`EntityPlayer` in front of me but I'd guess it does have equality as it's needed for other things Minecraft does and it would be odd for `equals(` to be useless.

Comment: So I would use the following?  if(e != this && !Camb.friend.contains(e) && e instanceof EntityPlayer &&getDistanceToEntity(e) < 3.95D){

That's saying if the person is NOT on the friends list, then do the following?

Comment: @Brad It's good to put hands on the code since I believe it's the primary way to learn, but if you're tweaking existing code as you are now and had to check this out, I suggest you read some tutorials first.

Comment: @Gamb Actually, wait, you're right. I'm not exactly sure with what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the SDK you're using to make this, but you can use this oneliner to check if an element is in an `ArrayList`.

```
myList.contains("friendname");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)